# How to use sticky inside a div with overflow

Tags: html, css

I have the following React code which is basically a screen with two headers. I would like to keep `header 2` sticky while it's inside `div` with overflow.

Yes, I know that it doesn't because it's inside a div with an overflow property. Is there any way I can solve this problem? I've tried so many approaches but nothing worked as I expected.

Preferentially,I'm looking for a solution using HTML and CSS.

```
<div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <div style={{ background: "green" }}>header 1</div>

  <div style={{ overflow: "auto" }}>
    <div
      style={{
        background: "red",
        position: "sticky",
        top: 0,
        height: "7000",
      }}
    >
      header 2
    </div>
    <div style={{ display: "inline-flex", gap: "5px" }}>
      {array.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          style={{ width: "200px", height: "2000px", background: "gray" }}
        >
          {item}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it looks like this
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `overflow: auto`? If it is to allow scrolling it looks like your current setup should already allow that. If it's just to allow overflows to be visible, maybe set `overflow: visible` instead?

Comment: Nop, header 1 and header 2 must be fixed while I scroll horizontally and vertically.